# Rails - three renders as HTML, as */* and as HTML on one query to root#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering

I'm see in log these strings after one query to root of my site:

```
Started GET "/" for 192.168.1.3 at 2013-07-30 17:55:36 +0600
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
Image Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `images`.* FROM `images` ORDER BY `images`.`id` DESC LIMIT 4
...

Started GET "/" for 192.168.1.3 at 2013-07-30 17:55:38 +0600
Processing by WelcomeController#index as */*
Image Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `images`.* FROM `images` ORDER BY `images`.`id` DESC LIMIT 4
...

Started GET "/" for 192.168.1.3 at 2013-07-30 17:55:41 +0600
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
Image Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `images`.* FROM `images` ORDER BY `images`.`id` DESC LIMIT 4
...
```

Is this a normally for Rails? Why the Rails do a triple processing for one query? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this doesn't look normal.

Probably something wrong in your server setup so requests to some assets or favicons or anything else end up routing to WelcomeController#index. It is quite hard to guess why this happens. So you should provide http requests recorded in your browser dev console (network tab), front-end server config (if you use one) and config/routes.rb file.

Comment: O! Yes. It is. I found that one image tag with property src have value "to be rewrited" instead "picture.gif". This property dynamically rewrited on some user actions and when i clean it (src = ""), rails will proccessing double instead triple. Than i seek the second thing, which may query second processing. I found it, when look, as you advise, the dev console in my chrome browser. This undefined picture was generate status "Redirect" in column "Initiator"

Comment: after while, i found second cause of doublicate render. The second thing was detecting in dev console. I look the column "Initiator" and found that load JavaScript library file was not found. After deleting link to this file i get one render for per query to root.